# How to create a new dataframe column with a function that is based on the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from binance.client import Client
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

client = Client("api","keys")

def getKlines4h(pairName):
    klines = client.get_historical_klines(pairName, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_4HOUR, "16 days ago UTC")

    candlestick_data = ["Close"]

    dt1 = pd.DataFrame([x[4:5] for x in klines], columns=candlestick_data)

    dt1 = dt1.astype('float64')
    return dt1


def getRsiForEachPair(df):
    dfSymbol = getKlines4h(df.symbol)
    dfSymRsi = rsi(dfSymbol)
    df['rsi'] = dfSymRsi['rsi_14'].iloc[-1]

def rma(x, n, y0):
    a = (n - 1) / n
    ak = a ** np.arange(len(x) - 1, -1, -1)
    return np.r_[np.full(n, np.nan), y0, np.cumsum(ak * x) / ak / n + y0 * a ** np.arange(1, len(x) + 1)]


def rsi(dfCrypto):
    df_rsi = dfCrypto
    df_rsi['Change'] = df_rsi['Close'].diff()
    df_rsi["Gain"] = df_rsi.Change.mask(df_rsi.Change < 0, 0.0)
    df_rsi["Loss"] = -df_rsi.Change.mask(df_rsi.Change > 0, -0.0)
    df_rsi['Avg_gain'] = rma(df_rsi.Gain[n + 1:].to_numpy(), n, np.nansum(df_rsi.Gain.to_numpy()[:n + 1]) / n)
    df_rsi['Avg_loss'] = rma(df_rsi.Loss[n + 1:].to_numpy(), n, np.nansum(df_rsi.Loss.to_numpy()[:n + 1]) / n)
    df_rsi['rs'] = df_rsi.Avg_gain / df_rsi.Avg_loss
    df_rsi['rsi_14'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df_rsi.rs))

    print(df_rsi.round(2))

    return df_rsi

def getPairs():
    allPairs = client.get_exchange_info()

    testd = pd.DataFrame(allPairs['symbols'])

    mask = testd['symbol'].str.contains('USDT')

    testd = testd[mask]
    testd.drop(testd.columns.difference(['symbol']), 1, inplace=True)

    return testd




df2 = getPairs()
df2.apply(getRsiForEachPair)

print(df2)
```

So recently I decided to learn how to work with Pandas and went ahead and started my first simple project using Pandas.
What I am trying to do:

Get all USDT pairs from Binance in a DataFrame `df2['symbol']`
Get RSI for each pair and then add it to `df2['rsi]`

Sadly with no luck. I don't quite get how I can add a new column that is based on the `df2['symbol']` column. Can somebody give me some direction on how I can accomplish this? I would appreciate some materials on the subjects as well(articles and etc.)

edit:

I solved the problem my making `getRsiForEachPair` get a string as an argument:

```
def getRsiForEachPair(pairName):
    dfSymbol = getKlines4h(pairName)
    dfSymRsi = rsi(dfSymbol)
    # df['rsi'] = dfSymRsi['rsi_14'].iloc[-1]
    print(pairName)
    return dfSymRsi['rsi_14'].iloc[-1]
```

and use `apply` like that:

```
df2['rsi'] = df2.apply(lambda x: getRsiForEachPair(x.symbol),axis = 1)
```

How can I speed this process tho? It takes extremely long time for 276 elements.

Dataframe:

```
          symbol
11       BTCUSDT
12       ETHUSDT
98       BNBUSDT
125      BCCUSDT
141      NEOUSDT
...          ...
1291    DODOUSDT
1295    CAKEUSDT
1307     ACMUSDT
1320  BADGERUSDT
1323     FISUSDT

[276 rows x 1 columns]
```

Dataframe for ACMUSDT with rsi:

```
     Close  Change   Gain   Loss  Avg_gain  Avg_loss        rs     rsi_14
0   24.422     NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
1   19.500  -4.922  0.000  4.922       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
2   16.125  -3.375  0.000  3.375       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
3   17.822   1.697  1.697  0.000       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
4   14.975  -2.847  0.000  2.847       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
5   16.225   1.250  1.250  0.000       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
6   19.334   3.109  3.109  0.000       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
7   17.350  -1.984  0.000  1.984       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
8   16.572  -0.778  0.000  0.778       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
9   14.230  -2.342  0.000  2.342       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
10  14.345   0.115  0.115  0.000       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
11  12.500  -1.845  0.000  1.845       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
12  13.493   0.993  0.993  0.000       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
13  12.850  -0.643  0.000  0.643       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
14  12.720  -0.130  0.000  0.130  0.511714  1.347571  0.379731  27.522090
15  11.670  -1.050  0.000  1.050  0.475163  1.326316  0.358258  26.376278
16  12.980   1.310  1.310  0.000  0.534794  1.231579  0.434235  30.276402
17  12.800  -0.180  0.000  0.180  0.496595  1.156467  0.429407  30.040919
18  11.989  -0.811  0.000  0.811  0.461124  1.131790  0.407429  28.948438
19  11.858  -0.131  0.000  0.131  0.428186  1.060305  0.403833  28.766459
20  11.716  -0.142  0.000  0.142  0.397602  0.994712  0.399715  28.556898
21  11.670  -0.046  0.000  0.046  0.369202  0.926947  0.398298  28.484507
22   9.306  -2.364  0.000  2.364  0.342830  1.029594  0.332976  24.979895
23   8.917  -0.389  0.000  0.389  0.318342  0.983837  0.323572  24.446878
24   9.763   0.846  0.846  0.000  0.356032  0.913563  0.389718  28.042960
25   8.649  -1.114  0.000  1.114  0.330601  0.927880  0.356297  26.269855
26   9.470   0.821  0.821  0.000  0.365630  0.861603  0.424360  29.793024
27   9.425  -0.045  0.000  0.045  0.339513  0.803274  0.422662  29.709226
28   9.762   0.337  0.337  0.000  0.339334  0.745897  0.454934  31.268340
29  13.375   3.613  3.613  0.000  0.573167  0.692619  0.827536  45.281514
30  12.592  -0.783  0.000  0.783  0.532227  0.699075  0.761330  43.224722
31  12.443  -0.149  0.000  0.149  0.494210  0.659784  0.749049  42.826077
32  13.200   0.757  0.757  0.000  0.512981  0.612656  0.837306  45.572500
33  13.800   0.600  0.600  0.000  0.519197  0.568895  0.912640  47.716259
34  13.300  -0.500  0.000  0.500  0.482111  0.563974  0.854847  46.087183
35  12.652  -0.648  0.000  0.648  0.447675  0.569976  0.785427  43.991004
36  12.660   0.008  0.008  0.000  0.416269  0.529263  0.786507  44.024853
37  12.654  -0.006  0.000  0.006  0.386536  0.491887  0.785822  44.003373
38  11.882  -0.772  0.000  0.772  0.358926  0.511895  0.701171  41.216956
39  12.112   0.230  0.230  0.000  0.349717  0.475331  0.735733  42.387459
40  12.098  -0.014  0.000  0.014  0.324737  0.442379  0.734070  42.332203
41  12.572   0.474  0.474  0.000  0.335399  0.410781  0.816492  44.948821
42  12.489  -0.083  0.000  0.083  0.311442  0.387368  0.803995  44.567484
43  12.106  -0.383  0.000  0.383  0.289196  0.387056  0.747169  42.764547
44  12.291   0.185  0.185  0.000  0.281753  0.359409  0.783936  43.944164
45  12.307   0.016  0.016  0.000  0.262771  0.333737  0.787360  44.051562
```

Comment: Why are you doing all of it with functions?

Comment: @delimiter How should I go about it?

Comment: Can you post a piece of your dataframe to illustrate the questions better?

Comment: Added it, I also fixed my problem but I wonder how can I make the code execute faster?

Comment: And what is your original dataframe with the other features?

Comment: @delimiter Added it